# Sublime Text 3 - Change line numbers column width

Tags: width, sublimetext3, sublimetext, line-numbers

I'm using Sublime Text 3 Build 3083 on a Mac.

The column that holds all the line numbers is taking way to much space of the screen:

[image]

Setting `"margin"` to a negative value fixes the width only on the right side:
[image]

How can I reduce the width for both left and right? Is there an alternative way?

Comment: I don't know if you *can* change the other side. That area is called the *"gutter"*, and is used by ST and plugins to display information regarding linting, spell checking, and other things, and they rely on it being a certain number of pixels wide.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: So I did a little more investigating, and it turns out there is a `"gutter"` setting. However, setting it to `false` removes the *entire* gutter, including the line numbers, so I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: No not really. But thanks for taking the time to investigate!

Answer (score 4):

```
{
  "fold_buttons": false,
  "margin": 0
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It turns out that the margin can be negative i.e. `"margin": -4`

Comment: This answer does not instruct where to set these preferences. It simply gives configuration changes. Please provide full context and instructions.

Comment: @EbonyMaw Look at the top of the window, select Preferences and than select Settings.

Comment: The previous comment should be integrated with the answer (and expanded to actually clearly show how to make the change). Steps of an answer should not be in comments.